# What is wrong with having a dynamic configuration file in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration

I have recently taken to converting my websites files into ones that work on any path. I am working on using Virtual Hosts to be able to maintain the same `.htaccess` file as on the main production server. My initialize file that includes all my models is written dynamically to find out the exact system file path and update the website accordingly so I can upload the whole website anywhere.

The trouble lies in the config file. Depending on whether I am on dev or on prod, I connect to a differert database. Therefore I have a small check first to see if I am running a local server. I do this by storing my naming conventions for my dev in an array and by looping through the array to see if the HTTP_HOST matches a value.

Example:

```
$dev_names = array('localhost','.dev');
```

However, when I mentioned this on Chat the other day, [a respected user told me](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5281114#5281114) that he never does this. Instead he has 2 config files and includes the right one at the right time? I didn't get though what was wrong with my approach?

Can you point out to me the flaws in my plan to help me understand the experts?

(PS.  For a bonus you can give me a quick run down on how a bootstrap works, heard that word being thrown around, not sure if it is written in PHP or whatever.)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/217594/911182

Comment: @Herbert perfect, just what i am looking for!

Comment: Happy to be of assistance. The link I gave you was the first one in the list of __Related__ links on the right side of this page. Also check _Questions that may already have your answer_ when you're typing your question. It may not have been listed, but it's usually a good place to start and helps prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see anything wrong with your approach, and I cannot think of a good reason not to do it.

Personally I do this in my php file;

```
 if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost')
 {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
 }
 else
 {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
 }
```

And then all my configs hang off that. Works extremely well - means I literally have zero config changes when moving between Dev & production

Comment: but what happens when you use Virtual Host and your site on local is called `mysite.dev`?

Comment: so just change the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] field to be whatever you like - i.e. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'mysite.dev'

Comment: Yeah so i check for the ending `.dev`. Just wanted to make sure we on the same wavelength!

Comment: This assumes that `$_SERVER` is safe and can't be spoofed, which isn't entirely true.

Comment: @YannisRizos who is gonna spoof on your own local server?

Comment: @InGodITrust On your local server, no one, but this bases `ENVIRONMENT` on `$_SERVER` for production as well.

Comment: @YannisRizos I know you can spoof the $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDRESS] - but where/how can you spoof the server_name? I googled it and couldnt find anything

Comment: @YannisRizos oh you mean spoof the prod into a local one? i get it

Comment: actually - i found one thing - refers to a bug that seems to be long gone? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136914/serverserver-name-variable-question

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what he was getting at is that your attempt to make your site portable isn't in fact all that portable. If you move it to a new server you'll have to edit your configuration file.

Specifically this becomes an issue when you're checking the config file into some sort of version control system and will be affecting someone else.
Ideally, you'll use something like this:

```
<?php // global config file which is checked into VCS
    $SETTING = "FOO";
    @include "config/local_settings.php"; // overrides go here
 ?>
```

You put all your local setting overrides in the local file, and don't commit it to the VCS. It's perfectly common to commit something like `local_settings_example.php` though, to give other users a heads-up as to what they need to customise. You can fill it with commented examples if you're feeling generous.

Comment: why will i have to edit my config file if i move to a new server? And how will it help to have two config files

Comment: this argument is mainly based on version control, meaning you have to edit any *.php that functions as an index to change the if statement aside from your repository, which isn't as "portable" as it may seem.

Answer (score 1):

I can only throw in my 2 cents on a setup I prefer. Mainly to avoid undesired version control overwrites or conflicts. To my point of view, it is the server that should decide if it's a production or development server, not a variable in a script that should be changed. An approach like the example below make it even possible to set an environment for an individual on a complete different development setup.

Starting by setting the variable

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN'];
```

to check for production or development environments. Locally to your own name with a dummy domain like @dev.elop.loc (e.g. dbf@dev.elop.loc) that would never exist for real. A function like so

```
// environment development check
function __env_dev($check) {
  return substr($_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN'], -(strlen($check))) === $check; 
}
// false = production
// true = development
__env_dev("@dev.elop.loc");
```

can determine the environment. To my experience, production servers always have a SERVER_ADMIN variable set (if not, they really should, even if it has to be the default you@example.com) to a real address, avoiding default you@example.com. If the support for the live server is in your own service/maintenance, it's not a big deal changing it to a real address to distinguish it from a development server ;)